# Need clarification in finding the probability of the problem.

Tags: probability

In an exam , students were sitting for theoretical and practical test.It is found that no students failed in both subject.$85$% passed in theoretical and $70$% passed in practical test. Calculate probability for a randomly chosen student

(1)failed in both test.

(2)passed in both test.

(3)passed in theoretical test,it is confirmed that the student passed in practical test.

**SOLVED**

Comment: You should only ask one thing per question.

Comment: yes, I actually want the answer of "b",and wanna check if "a" is correct or not.

Comment: I have done a, please delete b and ask it separately.

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince I´ve deleted my answer since the answer of Ross was sufficient for your.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a2, there are $15\%$ that failed theoretical and $30\%$ that failed practical.  As these sets are disjoint, there were $45\%$ that failed one test.  For a3 there were $70\%$ that passed practical and $55\%$ that passed both, so it is $\frac {55}{70}$

Comment: I had considered $100$ students.among them $85$ students passed in theoretical and $70$ students passed in practical. then isn't the number of students passed in both test $=85+70-100=60$ according to the formula?then , the probability shouldn't be $60/100=3/5$? where is my mistake?

Comment: But $85+70-100=55$

Comment: oh!!god !!...nothing to say !! thanks for finding the mistake....